# How do all those Javascript OpenID libraries work?

Tags: javascript, openid, openid-selector

There are several OpenID libraries implemented in Javascript (like [openid-realselector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/), [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/), [jquery.opendid](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml)). How do all these work? Do they just provide and call the OpenID provider and then the provider provides some data (**how?**) and redirects back to my site (**to where exactly?**)? And now is it my part on the server side to fetch that data somehow and use it to log in my user? I looked at the code of *openid-selector*, but don't see where to provide a callback url to my site. So I am not sure anymore if the above scenario is really the way how this all works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The libraries you have mentioned are OpenID *selectors*, that is, glorified forms allowing for easy selection of a provider. They have nothing to do with the protocol, which must be implemented server-side.

As for "how do they work", they simply submit a form with a certain field (`openid_identifier`). Depending on the button you click, that field has different values, and if you don't click on any, you simply have to input it yourself. Then, a server-side code gets the value, passes it to a library that does handles openid.

You can find a list of OpenID (server-side) libraries on http://openid.net/developers/libraries/.